# Rotation of a circle over another circle

Tags: geometry, circles, rotations

[image]

Let the circle $d$ rotates over the circle $c$. If the angle rotation to be of 0 to 360, then how many times does the circle $d$ rotate during that process?

Since the total external angle is 360, I think the rotation on circle ( or any polygon) to be $s+1$ for real number $s$. If this is true, then we should find $s$.

Comment: It depends on the circumference of the larger circle can accommodate how many circumference of the smaller circle. The result is not necessarily a whole number. Also, don't understand what s is.

Comment: Do you mean circle c's circumference remains fixed while circle d rolls along it?

Answer (score 0):

The circle $d$ is rotating with an angular speed which is $\dfrac{R_c}{R_d}$ times the ones of circle $c$, with respect to their respective centers. However, the center of $d$ is moving.

So at the end the angle $\theta_d$ follows the following rule:

$\theta_d=(\dfrac{R_c}{R_c}+1)\theta_c$

Comment: What is $\theta_{d}$ and $\theta_{c}$ here?

Comment: $\theta_d$ is the angle of rotation of the initial point of contact of $d$ on $c$ and $\theta_c$ is the angle between the initial point of contact and the current one.